# mobile apps: restful api or sdk dynamodb

Tags: android, node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm building my first app which uses an external database for storing data..

And I'm struggling with the following question:
How to connect with my database: use the Amazon DynamoDB sdk for Android or create a restful api based on NodeJS on my own server, which passes the data to DynamoDB?

I'm very new to this and when I look over the internet I see amazon suggesting to use the SDK.

The only problem is, if I want to change the data structure in the feature, what kind of problems will my users experience with the current versions of the app? And is it safe to save my Amazon keys inside the app (cause people may be able to decompile the app)?

On the other hand, I do have to pay for the extra server which handles the connections between my app and DynamoDB. So... is it worth it?

So I'm quite struggling with this.... What do you guys think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go for direct access from your mobile application to DynamoDB.
This would allow you to scale your application much easier : you do not need to maintain, operate, secure a middle layer, AWS does that for you.  You will also save on the cost of running your couple of NodeJS servers, load balancers etc ...

You should not store access keys / secret keys in your application but rather use AWS Cognito Identity service to dynamically receive access keys and secret keys for your user session.  These keys will be limited in scope to whatever permission you define for your Cognito users and limited in time (default is 15 min)

Cognito works with backend identity providers to authenticate your users (Facebook, Google, Amazon, openID connect or your own backend) and can also work with unauthenticated users.

More about Cognito : http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/
More about Cognito ID for Android Mobile Applications :http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html

Comment: Thank you for your complete and clear answer :) And the answer I was hoping for haha, saves me quite some time to configure a node app for the middle layer. I'll take a look at Cognito!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that the accepted answer is complete because it does not acknowledge use cases, and it does not address the question asked of "what if I want to change the data structure." Well, if you have outdated clients, and change the data structure of the documents in your nosql database, then those clients will not be able to access it. I don't believe DynamoDB offers a middleware platform to support this kind of old-to-new model adaptation. You'll have to force an update to your clients.

In fact, there are many operations beyond user-based permissions (which Cognito does do well) like this that you might need middleware for. Perhaps you want sorting logic to occur at request-time, and not maintain a copy of that sorting logic in every client application.

The question of "is it worth it" probably depends on the complexity of your application and your users' relationship with the data (ie. if the presentation layer basically just wrapped data -- then directly access DynamoDB. If you your presentation layer is not just wrapped data, then you should probably use custom middleware). In truth, I stumbled upon this question while running my own cost-benefit analysis, and am not sure which approach I will take. Another major factor of mine is that I might choose to switch database solutions in the future.. this will be more challenging to update on every client, if my clients are directly accessing the DB.

The one certain conclusion I've reached is that you should use middleware *somewhere* in your system, such that you can decouple your database vendor from either the client logic or the server logic as much as possible, eg. in a mobile app:
    writeToDatabase(Data data){writeToDynamo(data);}

To achieve this, AWS suggests using Amazon Api Gateway as a proxy for AWS services, and even has premade configurations for Amazon API Gateway to behave as AWS service proxy.